# C# winforms connection using XAMPP

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, phpmyadmin

I have a problem of copying a row of data from one table to another in C# using xampp server without using a textbox

Comment: Not only is this not a question, but it also makes 0 sense. What tables? What role does XAMPP play? Why would you need a textbox (or not)?

Comment: Please, go read [ask], take the [tour], then reconsider the wording of this. Even if I tried very hard, I wouldn't even know how to help.